# Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, overrides, magento2, requirejs

As Magento2 is using RequireJS for loading scripts, and there's no more **skin** folder, I've stuck with a problem:

*How can I replace Magento's module JS file by my modified version?*

For example — the **opc-checkout-method.js** which belongs to Magento_Checkout extension. It's not defined in the requirejs-config.js file, as far as I can see.

My extension is loaded after **Magento_Checkout**, so its requirejs-config.js data is appended at the end of resulting requirejs-config file.

Or should I do it in some other way, without replacing the whole script?

Comment: I would imagine you shouldn't be replacing the file so much as replacing the function(s) on the object loaded by the file.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

There is no more skin folder but you can still use themes.

As a proof of concept I used you example with `op-checkout-method.js` and this this.

**Preconditions:**

- Magento2-beta11 installed
- Default theme active (blank).
- No files generated in the `pub/static` folder (remove the pub/static/frontend folder)

**Actions:**

- Copied the `op-checkout-method.js` file from it's module location `app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/opc-checkout-method.js` to the blank theme to `app/design/frontend/Magento/blank/Magento_Checkout/web/js/opc-checkout-method.js`
- edited the clone file and added a `console.log('something')` or `alert('something')` in the `_create` function of the `mage.opcCheckoutMethod` widget.
- cleared browser cache.

**Result:**

- When the checkout page loads I see my alert displayed or the text logged in the console.

**Related Info:**

If I run from cli `php dev/tools/Magento/Tools/View/deploy.php` (the script that publishes the static resources) my new js file gets placed in `pub/static/frontend/Magento/blank/en_US/Magento_Checkout/js/opc-checkout-method.js`

**[EDIT]**

I found a way to do it via a module.

In `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add this:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/opc-checkout-method':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/opc-checkout-method'
        }
    }
};
```

Then create the file `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/opc-checkout-method.js` with your content.

For testing purposes I cloned the original file and just added again a `console.log` in the `_create` function.

Also remember to regenerate the public resources for frontend.

Comment: Thanks, Marius! Is it possible to do similar things inside extension?

Comment: I don't think you van do that from an extension. that was not possible in magento 1 unless you changed the checkout template completely. But I will look for a way to do it.

Comment: Thanks again, Marius. I'm trying to implement customized checkout, which overrides default one, and I'm stuck with JS overrides.

Comment: @DmitryR. See my update to the answer.

Comment: the place for requirejs-config.js is now Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Comment: @Marius I could able to perform what you suggested but how to achieve if any template (html file) overriding associated with js file. For example `Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection.js' has `template: 'ui/form/components/collection' which i need to overwrite. please help me its urgent

Comment: can we override in  custom theme  `app/design/frontend/[Namespace]/[Module]/Magento_Checkout/js/opc-checkout-method.js`  without `requirejs-config.js`  file

Comment: @Marius i need to make changes into `pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/form/element/multiselect.js` file how can i rewrite it into my extension?

Comment: I try to override `/var/www/html/projectname/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/file-uploader.js`` this file but cant'

Comment: @Marius Thank you ! how can we know which js will by applied if more than one module extend/override the same core js ?

Comment: "Second mouse gets the cheese". The module that is loaded last will take over.

Comment: @Marius. can I do like that ? Only some functions I need to require modify in my custom module. I do that using mixins. But, It's also call in catalog page. I just want to call in my custom module only. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/253507/magenot-2-mixin-js-should-only-call-in-custom-module-page  Can you please help me?

Comment: how do i override braintree js file which renders in html any help

Comment: how to overide default library js files?

Comment: For some reason it still loads the original one, even after clearing the browser cache
EDIT: Ok, I also had to flush cache with `cache:flush`

Answer (score 15):

Here's the official doc about extending/replacing default JS components:
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/javascript/custom/

Feedback is welcome!

Comment: Welcome to MagentoSE. This answer would be more useful to future users if you added the answer here, instead of just the link. If the link breaks in the future, searchers won't find the information you are referencing.

Comment: That's a fair point but we add 301 redirects when topics move so the risk of 404s are minimized.

Answer (score 7):

To use a custom implementation of an existing Magento or custom vendor JS component that's not defined in the `requirejs-config.js` copy the custom component source file to your theme JS files:

`app/design/frontend/<your-vendor>/<your-theme>/<vendor_module>/web/js/<source_file>`