# how to extend .js and .html files in Magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento-2.0, html, customer-address, uicomponent

I'm extending `customer address` for these I have to **modify/extend** `vendor/Magento/module-ui` core files.

**i.e**

`root/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/collection.js`

**and**

```
root/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/components/collection.html
```

When I have modified core files it's working fine, But this is not good procedure/idea to extend.

So I have created the vendor name as `Magento` in `root/app/code/` and I have placed modified above files to same folder in local.

**i.e**

`root/app/code/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/components/collection.js`

**and**

```
root/app/code/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/templates/form/components/collection.html
```

After placing those files I have cleared the cache. But still it's not showing my changes.

I have ran `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command also but no luck.

Could you please suggest me how to do this?

Comment: @ArkadiyCh, I have created from `root/app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Ui` folder also. but no luck. Can you please tell me path where i need to create?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Achieved my self.

Create `requirejs-config.js` file from **Learning/HelloWorld/view/base** and paste below code

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/collection':'Learning_HelloWorld/js/form/components/collection'
        }
    }
};
```

Create `collection.js` file from **Learning/HelloWorld/view/base/web/js/form/components** and copy paste core code and modyfie it.

```
   /**
     * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    define([
        'underscore',
        'mageUtils',
        'uiRegistry',
        'uiComponent',
        'uiLayout',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm'
    ], function (_, utils, registry, Component, layout, confirm) {
        'use strict';

        var childTemplate = {
            parent: '${ $.$data.name }',
            name: '${ $.$data.childIndex }',
            dataScope: '${ $.name }',
            nodeTemplate: '${ $.$data.name }.${ $.$data.itemTemplate }'
        };

        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                lastIndex: 0,
                template: 'Learning_HelloWorld/form/components/collection'
            },

/* my custom methods */
            sendAddress: function (elem) {
                var self = this;
                self._sendAddress(elem);
            },

/* my custom methods */
            _sendAddress: function (elem) {


                this.bubble('update');
            }

        });
    });
```

Create `collection.html` file from **Learning/HelloWorld/view/base/web/template/form/components** path and paste core code and modify it

```
   <div class="ui-tabs">
<!-- My Extra html code -->
     <button type="button" data-bind="click: $parent.sendAddress.bind($parent, element)">
         Send this Address
     </button>
    </div>
```

Now run the below commands.

1. setup:upgrade
2. setup:static-content:deploy

Now it will work.

Feel free to ask if any queries.

Comment: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js

Comment: Hi @Magento two can you please help me, How to over ride confirm.js.

Comment: @shivashankarm create a separate thread and tag me, then everyone will help you.

Comment: Hi @magento two Please find the link :https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/194763/49102

Answer (score 1):

One module is registered under one path, that's why it can read from vendor, but cannot from app/code.

Comment: then where I need to create?

Comment: I have created from `root/app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_Ui` folder also. but no luck. Can you please tell me path where i need to create?

Comment: I'd create my own module to check, and try to put not in base but in adminhtml folder

Comment: any help on this?

Comment: any update on this how to extend `.js` and `.html` files?