# Override vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides

Can anyone help how to over ride

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/modal/confirm.js
```

file in theme.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

create below path in your theme,

```
app/design/frontend/{Vendorname}/{themename}/Magento_Ui/web/js/modal/confirm.js
```

Run

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

And Run

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Will this override for front end only?
How did the change will get on both admin and front end without using duplicate file?

Comment: @Rakesh, Shall i do this with in the custom module ,because i dont want to add it in theme

Comment: Not Working !! I'm on 2.3 CE.

Answer (score 0):

Rakesh Jesadiya solution worked for me on Magento 2.3, but I had to run the `setup:upgrade` before the `setup:static-content:deploy`