# How to add custom js on checkout page Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript

When customizing checkout page, I want to add new custom js to check when a specific Payment is checked. Can I use Knockout Js or re-use exist js functions of payment? And, what's the best practice for this?

[image]

Comment: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html

Comment: See this tutorial also: http://oyenetwork.com/articles/magento2-devliery-date-module-creation-from-scratch/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a way to do this. We're going to [override the core js](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2).

If we inspect the element of payment checkbox, as we can see, Magento uses a function - `selectPaymentMethod` - to check select action. We will override this core function.

[image]

In your custom module, create `requirejs-config.js` which declares our override function.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-payment-method':
                'Boolfly_PaymentFee/js/action/payment/select-payment-method'
        }
    }
};
```

For example, our override function:

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Boolfly_PaymentFee/js/action/checkout/cart/totals',
        'jquery/jquery-storageapi',
    ],
    function($, ko ,quote, totals) {
        'use strict';

        return function (paymentMethod) {
            //Our custom code should be here.
            if(paymentMethod.method == 'paymentfee')
            {
                alert('Payment Fee');
                quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);

            } else {
                quote.paymentMethod(paymentMethod);
            }

        }
    }
);
```

I'm not sure about the best way to tackle my problem. However, this way can resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add an by extending checkout_index_index.xml which you should add to

```
/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<themename>/Magento_Checkout/layout/
```

adding the follwing:

```
 <head>
   <link src="<url of your js file>"/>
 </head>
```

Comment: You didn't fully understand my question: `Can I use Knockout Js? And, what's the best practice for this?`.

Comment: Sorry about that but in fact, now you can add a new knockout file to your checkout right ;-)

Comment: Can i re-use exist js functions of payment? When I don't want to use `checkout_index_index.xml` to add new custom js.