# When validation correct do

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2

On the shipping step in checkout I want to add a class to a form field if the validation of that field is successful but i'm not sure in what JS file I need to add this or where I should add a custom JS file. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a new js file and adding it in the define in shipping.js.

In the js I check if the field's parents have an _error classes, if so the border turns red otherwise it gets a green border after the minimum length is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Default validation js file is **validation.js** located in lib/web/mage

**Add custom js file**
Create **checkout_index_index.xml** under /app/design/frontend///Magento_Checkout/layout/ folder and add the follwing:

```
<head>
   <link src="<url of your js file>"/>
 </head>
```

Also read this topic maybe it's helpful
[How to add custom js on checkout page Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116196/how-to-add-custom-js-on-checkout-page-magento-2)