# How to change jQuery version in Magento2

Tags: magento2, jquery

Magento 2.1.2 bundled with jQuery 1.11. How it possible to replace it with jQuery 2.1?

Comment: Why u want to replace? By replacing JS it will cause so many issues.

Comment: When I will add FB.init that time need to add function with ajax post, so I need to add other jquery. and comes issue so let me figure out this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Original file path is here

**magento\vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\jquery.js**

You should overwrite in your theme so path will be

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\web\js\jquery.js**

How to override JS file

[Extending/overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

Comment: This doesn't work for version 2.2.4

Comment: hi @Ankit, can you update the full code, with require js?

Comment: Does not work. Tried in 2.3

Answer (score 5):

Correct place to put jquery update is
`"your_theme"/web/jquery.js`
dont forget to propper cleare caches
just now got it working.
Also jquery-migrate.js needs to be updated and seems that patch for jquery.mobile.custom.js needed and fix for knockout/template/rendered.js to fix self closing nodes.

Magento 2.4

Answer (score 1):

Change the jquey file in `lib` folder.

**lib/web/jquery.js**