# Magento 2 properly update core jquery lib

Tags: magento2, jquery

I keep seeing this warning in my console (firefox dev-console)

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated  jquery-migrate.js:41:4
console.trace():  jquery-migrate.js:43
    migrateWarn ---.com/static/version1498093005/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:43:5
    get ---.com/static/version1498093005/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery/jquery-migrate.js:58:6
    f< ---.com/static/version1498093005/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9:677
    <anonymous> ---.com/static/version1498093005/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/jquery/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js:9:389
    <anonymous>
```

I'd really like to update it to a newer version.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1: JS override**

You can override the original jQuery file to the one you desired. If you have an own theme, you can put the latest `jquery.js` file into `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\web\js\`. The system will use your jQuery file instead.

Ref: [How to change jQuery version in Magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/150138/how-to-change-jquery-version-in-magento2)

**Method 2: Use CDN**

It also override the original theme JS file, and using your theme files. But this time, we don't download the `jquery.js` file. We always get the latest one.

1. Go to `app\design\frontend\Vendor\Theme\Magento_Theme\layout\default_head_blocks.xml`. You can create this file if you don't have.
2. Add the following code on the file

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <head>
       <!--Remove default jquery, or it will cause conflict-->
       <remove src="lib\web\jquery.js"/>
       <!--Include CDN-->
       <script
             src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
             integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
             crossorigin="anonymous" src_type="url"></script>
   </head>
   ```

You can change to any jQuery versions as you want. For the `<script>` part, you can refer to https://code.jquery.com/ . And, remember to add `src_type="url"` before closing tag.

3. If you have enabled cache, clear the cache.

Ref: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_css_remove

Comment: What about the require js dependency id of jQuery when you change the filename from jquery.js to jquery-3.2.1.min.js?

Comment: Also method #1 does not work for magento version 2.2.4

Comment: @FrankGroot, you found any answer for this?