# Magento 2: specify jquery version for external js library

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use a jquery plugin for a flipbook on magento 2 but it's not working with my version of jquery.
On magento 2 i'm using v1.12.4 and the jquery plugin is using v1.11.0.

Is there a way to specify which version of jquery is required?

thanks!

Comment: As a warning you may run into issues if you load multiple versions of jQuery, a better fix would be to use a version of the flipbook plugin that's compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify your theme's `default_head_blocks.xml` file.

You can find the how to do it here:

[Magento 2 properly update core jquery lib](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/180372/magento-2-properly-update-core-jquery-lib)