# Magento Optimization -> 1- Upgrade Magento jquery version to 3.6 | 2 - use varnish cache , install and configure varnish cache on your demo stores

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.4

Can anyone know how to do these tasks, or any hint?

Comment: have a look to this accepted answer for the jquery question:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/195092/magento-2-load-latest-version-jquery-in-custom-module
But there is a problem: The newer releases break existing code. There are a lot of magento widgets with jquery. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/26547

Answer (score 0):

You can install Redis and Varnish caching on your server and the configure magento to use these services for performance