# Override js core function in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, overrides

in backend there is  **module-sales/view/adminhtml/web/order/create/scripts.js**, and inside that js there is a function like this :

```
loadShippingRates : function(){
            this.isShippingMethodReseted = false;
            this.loadArea(['shipping_method', 'totals'], true, {collect_shipping_rates: 1});
        }
```

i want to change the function, so it will send another data to loadArea function like this:

```
loadShippingRates : function(){
            this.isShippingMethodReseted = false; 
            var yeezy= jQuery('#order-billing_address_yeezy').val();
            this.loadArea(['shipping_method', 'totals'], true, {collect_shipping_rates: 1, yeezy_is_ready_yoo: yeezy});
        }
```

when i change from pub/static my custom function works fine, but i don't know how to override this function from custom extension

Comment: check out this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can override core js file using below way,

**app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/order/create/script.js**

Keep requirejs-config.js file at below location for override core js file,
**app/code/Namespace/Modulename/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js**

```
 var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                "Magento_Sales/js/order/create/script": 'Namespace_Modulename/js/order/create/script',
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: should i write all the code or just the function i want to rewrite?

Comment: you can write all code.

Comment: can i just write the function that i want to override?

Comment: i havent try with only function, May be you can done it with only function. jsut try with that and check.

Comment: have you check using only function?

Comment: it's not gonna work if i only write my function

Comment: If you want to rewrite only one function you need to use 'mixins' - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html