# How to override .js file in Magento 2 via require-JS?

Tags: magento2

I need to override `Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\web\js\order\create\scripts.js` via `requirejs-config.js` in Magento 2?

Comment: If the answer is useful and it is really suggested to other than accept it. So other people also know which answer is useful. I used **Mayank zalavadia's** answer and its working for me.

Answer (score 3):

Create `require-js.config` file at  [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/require-js.config and add following code on that file.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            "customscripts": "[Namespace]_[Module]/js/customscripts",
            "Magento_Sales/js/order/create/scripts": "[Namespace]_[Module]/js/customscripts",
        }
    }
};
```

And create `customscripts.js` file at [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/customscripts.js

And make sure you have added `sequence` in your `module.xml` file.

```
<module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence name="Opera_Base" />
</module>
```

That's it.

Comment: @Ramanathan please follow as per I mention here. And I am sure you'll definitely able to override js.

Answer (score 1):

You can override js using following code in `[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/require-js.config`

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento\Sales\view\adminhtml\web\js\order\create\scripts.js':'[Vendor]_[Module]/js/your-js-file'
        }
    }
};
```

Remember that you must not write .js for your file name.
Don't forget to run following commands after it ;

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help you.

For your reference : 
[Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

[Override core javascript files in Magento 2](http://www.magento.scommerce-mage.co.uk/override-core-javascript-files-magento-2.html)

[How to Override Magento JS Core in Magento 2](https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/how-to-override-magento-js-core-in-magento-2/)