# Custom options not loading after saving the product in admin - Magento 2.1.7

Tags: javascript, overrides, custom-options, magento-2.1.7, bug

I tried creating few custom options for a product. A field type and dropdown type. After saving the product getting a javascript error in the console as shown in the screenshot

```
data.forEach is not a function.
```

[image]

If I keep the field type option at last, then no javascript error. If it is kept as the first option, then experiencing this error.

It is a core issue and I found a solution here https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10321. But I want to know how to override this file using the custom module instead of changing the core file.

**File Path to override:** `vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\dynamic-rows\dynamic-rows-grid.js`

**I tried this solution with both adminhtml and base as path but it didn't work.**

Create a file at below location,

```
Custom/Modulename/view/adminhtml/requirejs-config.js

    var config = {  
    map: {
        '*': {
            "Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid": 'Custom_Modulename/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid'
        }
    }
};
```

create a file at location,

```
Custom/Modulename/view/adminhtml/web/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid.js
```

Copy content from core file to your custom file and run these commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question about extending the core javascript [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60667/50771). Hope it help.