# Override Magento UI js file

Tags: magento2, javascript, overrides, folder

How can I override this file on my theme?

```
/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

I'm a newbie to M2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom module `[Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js` add this

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/Magento_Ui/js/view/messages.js':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/view/messages.js'
        }
    }
};
```

your overridden js file should be here `[Namespace]_[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

run below command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade && php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

read more here: [Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

Comment: I don't see the view folder on the theme but I saw theme-name/require-config.js. Is it the same file?

Comment: you need to create require-config.js file get reference [here](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/override-core-javascript-files-magento-2.html)

Comment: I have this on theme-folder/require-config.js
`var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            "flexslider":'Magento_Theme/js/jquery.flexslider.min',
            "amShopbyFilterSlider": "js/amShopby"
        }
    }
};`
Do I still need to create folders and file (theme-name/view/frontend/require-config.js)

Comment: try to append this 'Magento_Ui/Magento_Ui/js/view/messages.js':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/view/messages.js' and check it work or not.

Comment: I accepted your answer because it's correct when you are on a module. But for your theme I think it's different? Isn't it just the folder?

Comment: Two comments, just in case: `Magento_Ui` should be only once. And you shouldn't put `.js` on the file. So it should be: `'Magento_Ui/js/view/messages':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/view/messages'`