# How to override the js in magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7.1

I want to override core js in custom module.

```
    define([
        'quickSearch',
        'jquery',
        'underscore',
        'mage/template',
        'mage/translate',
        'jquery/ui'
    ], function (quickSearch, $, _, mageTemplate, $translate) {
        'use strict';

        var autoComplete = {
            ajaxRequest: null,
            url: null,
            timer: null,
            delay: 500,
            currentUrlEncoded: null,
            minSizePopup: 700,
            siz

ePopupBreakpoint: 550,
        mobileView: 768,
        windowWidth: $(window).width(),
        proportionSide: 0.33,

        init: function (url, layout, currentUrlEncoded) {
            this.url = url;
            this.layout = layout;
            this.currentUrlEncoded = currentUrlEncoded;
            this.extend();
        },

        extend: function () {
            var _caller = this;
            var methods = {
                options: {                   
                    responseFieldElements: '.search-item',
                    minChars: this.layout.minChars
                },
                _onPropertyChange: function () {
                    if (_caller.timer != null) {
                        clearTimeout(_caller.timer);
                    }
                    _caller.timer = setTimeout(function () {
                        _caller._onPropertyChange.call(this);
                    }.bind(this), _caller.delay);
                },

                _create: this._create,               
                _searchDifineHideOrClear: this.difineHideOrClear,              
            };
            $.extend(true, quickSearch.prototype, methods);
        },

        _create: function () {           
            this._searchDifineHideOrClear();          
        },
        difineHideOrClear: function () { 
            var self = this;

            $('body').on('click', function (e) { 
                var target = $(e.target);

                if (target.hasClass('search-close')) { 
                    self._searchClearField();
                }

                if (!target.closest('.search-form-container').length) { 
                    self._searchHidePopup();
                }
            });
        },        

    };

    return autoComplete;
});
```

> Mixin Js :-

```
config: {
        mixins: {
            'XXX_YYY/js/autocomplete': {
                'AAA_ZZZ/js/autocomplete': true
            }
        }
    }
```

**Js file**

```
define([
    'quickSearch',
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mage/template',
    'mage/translate',
    'jquery/ui'
], function (quickSearch, $, _, mageTemplate, $translate) {
    'use strict';

    var mixin = {
        difineHideOrClear: function () { 
            var self = this;

            //clear field
            $('.search-close').on('click', function (e) { 
                self._searchClearField();
            });

            $('body').on('click', function (e) {
                var target = $(e.target);

                if (target.hasClass('search-close')) {
                    self._searchClearField();
                }

                if (!target.closest('.search-form-container').length) {
                    self._searchHidePopup();
                }
            });
        }
    };
    return function (target) {
        return target.extend(mixin);


      };
    });
```

Comment: I have tried to override using mixin ...but not working

Comment: Mixin is used to extend the functionality not for rewriting, in order to override you gotta use requirejs-config.js to map the core to your overridden path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

Comment: we use mixin only for widget type?

Answer (score 0):

**add this:**

> [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            '[Namespace]_[Module]/js/js-file-name':  //Path Of Js Which You Override
            '[Namespace]_[Module]/js/js-file-name' //Your Js Path
        }
    }
};
```

And Create Js File In Location `"[Namespace]_[Module]/js/js-file-name"`

Answer (score 0):

Create **requirejs-config.js** file as :

> [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'PathOfFileYouWantToOverride':[Namespace]_[Module]/js/nameofthefile'
        }
    }
};
```