# How to override js file of base folder in Magento_Ui?

Tags: magento2.2

I want to override the sizes.js in location:

> /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/paging/sizes.js

I want to remove "Custom" and "200" options from admin grid per page dropdown.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try following solution.

> [Vendor]/[Module/view/base/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/paging/sizes':'[Vendor]_[Module]/js/grid/paging/sizes'
        }
    }
};
```

> [Vendor]/[Module/view/base/web/js/grid/paging/sizes.js

```
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */

    /**
     * @api
     */
    define([
        'ko',
        'underscore',
        'mageUtils',
        'uiElement'
    ], function (ko, _, utils, Element) {
        'use strict';

        return Element.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: '[Vendor]_[Module]/grid/paging/sizes',
                value: 20,
                minSize: 1,
                maxSize: 999,
                options: {
                    '20': {
                        value: 20,
                        label: 20
                    },
                    '30': {
                        value: 30,
                        label: 30
                    },
                    '50': {
                        value: 50,
                        label: 50
                    },
                    '100': {
                        value: 100,
                        label: 100
                    },
                    '200': {
                        value: 200,
                        label: 200
                    }
                },
                statefull: {
                    options: true,
                    value: true
                },
                listens: {
                    value: 'onValueChange',
                    options: 'onSizesChange'
                }
            },

            /**
             * Initializes sizes component.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            initialize: function () {
                this._super()
                    .updateArray();

                this.removeSize(200)
                    .discardCustom();

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Initializes observable properties.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            initObservable: function () {
                this._super()
                    .track([
                        'value',
                        'editing',
                        'customVisible',
                        'customValue'
                    ])
                    .track({
                        optionsArray: []
                    });

                this._value = ko.pureComputed({
                    read: ko.getObservable(this, 'value'),

                    /**
                     * Validates input field prior to updating 'value' property.
                     */
                    write: function (value) {
                        value = this.normalize(value);

                        this.value = value;
                        this._value.notifySubscribers(value);
                    },

                    owner: this
                });

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Starts editing of the specified size.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value of the size.
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            edit: function (value) {
                this.editing = value;

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Discards changes made to the currently editable size.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            discardEditing: function () {
                var value = this.editing;

                if (value) {
                    this.updateSize(value, value);
                }

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Invokes 'discardEditing' and 'discardCustom' actions.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            discardAll: function () {
                this.discardEditing()
                    .discardCustom();

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Returns value of the first size.
             *
             * @returns {Number}
             */
            getFirst: function () {
                return this.optionsArray[0].value;
            },

            /**
             * Returns size which matches specified value.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value of the item.
             * @returns {Object|Undefined}
             */
            getSize: function (value) {
                return this.options[value];
            },

            /**
             * Sets current size to the specified value.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value of the size.
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            setSize: function (value) {
                this.value = value;

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Adds a new value to sizes list.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be added.
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            addSize: function (value) {
                var size;

                if (!this.hasSize(value)) {
                    size = this.createSize(value);

                    this.set('options.' + value, size);
                }

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Removes provided value from the sizes list.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be removed.
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            removeSize: function (value) {
                if (!this.hasSize(value)) {
                    return this;
                }

                this.remove('options.' + value);

                if (this.isSelected(value)) {
                    this.setSize(this.getFirst());
                }

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Updates existing value to the provided one. If new value
             * is not specified, then sizes' '_value' property will be taken.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Existing value that should be updated.
             * @param {(Number|String)} [newValue=size._value] - New size value.
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            updateSize: function (value, newValue) {
                var size = this.getSize(value);

                if (!size) {
                    return this;
                }

                newValue = newValue || size._value;

                if (isNaN(+newValue)) {
                    this.discardEditing();

                    return this;
                }

                newValue = this.normalize(newValue);

                this.remove('options.' + value)
                    .addSize(newValue);

                if (this.isSelected(value)) {
                    this.setSize(newValue);
                }

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Creates new editable size instance with the provided value.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value of the size.
             * @returns {Object}
             */
            createSize: function (value) {
                return {
                    value: value,
                    label: value,
                    _value: value,
                    editable: true
                };
            },

            /**
             * Checks if provided value exists in the sizes list.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be checked.
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            hasSize: function (value) {
                return !!this.getSize(value);
            },

            /**
             * Hides and clears custom field.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            discardCustom: function () {
                this.hideCustom()
                    .clearCustom();

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Shows custom field.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            showCustom: function () {
                this.customVisible = true;

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Hides custom field.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            hideCustom: function () {
                this.customVisible = false;

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Empties value of the custom field.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            clearCustom: function () {
                this.customValue = '';

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Adds a new size specified in the custom field.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            applyCustom: function () {
                var value = this.customValue;

                value = this.normalize(value);

                this.addSize(value)
                    .setSize(value)
                    .discardCustom();

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Checks if custom field is visible.
             *
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            isCustomVisible: function () {
                return this.customVisible;
            },

            /**
             * Converts provided value to a number and puts
             * it in range between 'minSize' and 'maxSize' properties.
             *
             * @param {(Number|String)} value - Value to be normalized.
             * @returns {Number}
             */
            normalize: function (value) {
                value = +value;

                if (isNaN(value)) {
                    return this.getFirst();
                }

                return utils.inRange(Math.round(value), this.minSize, this.maxSize);
            },

            /**
             * Updates the array of options.
             *
             * @returns {Sizes} Chainable.
             */
            updateArray: function () {
                var array = _.values(this.options);

                this.optionsArray = _.sortBy(array, 'value');

                return this;
            },

            /**
             * Checks if provided value is in editing state.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be checked.
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            isEditing: function (value) {
                return this.editing === value;
            },

            /**
             * Checks if provided value is selected.
             *
             * @param {Number} value - Value to be checked.
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            isSelected: function (value) {
                return this.value === value;
            },

            /**
             * Listener of the 'value' property changes.
             */
            onValueChange: function () {
                this.discardAll()
                    .trigger('close');
            },

            /**
             * Listener of the 'options' object changes.
             */
            onSizesChange: function () {
                this.editing = false;

                this.updateArray();
            }
        });
    });
```

Here only 2 changes are there. template parameter and initialize function. Replace your module name in template parameter.

> [Vendor]/[Module]/view/base/web/template/grid/paging/sizes.html

```
<div class="selectmenu" collapsible="">
    <div class="selectmenu-value" openCollapsible="">
        <input type="text" ko-value="_value" attr="id: index" autoselect/>
    </div>
    <button class="selectmenu-toggle" type="button" css="_active: $collapsible.opened" toggleCollapsible>
        <span translate="'Select'"/>
    </button>
    <div class="selectmenu-items" css="_active: $collapsible.opened" outerClick="discardAll.bind($data)">
        <ul>
            <li repeat="foreach: optionsArray, item: '$size'" css="_edit: isEditing($size().value)">
                <div class="selectmenu-item-edit" if="$size().editable" keyboard="13: updateSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                    <input class="admin__control-text" type="text"
                        ko-value="$size()._value" hasFocus="isEditing($size().value)"/>
                    <button class="action-save" type="button" click="updateSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                        <span translate="'Save'"/>
                    </button>
                    <button class="action-delete" type="button" click="removeSize.bind($data, $size().value, false)">
                        <span translate="'Delete'"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="selectmenu-item">
                    <button class="selectmenu-item-action" type="button" text="$size().label" click="setSize.bind($data, $size().value)"/>
                    <button class="action-edit" type="button" if="$size().editable"
                        data-bind="
                            click: function () {
                                discardCustom().edit($size().value);
                            }">
                        <span translate="'Edit'"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>

            <li css="_edit: isCustomVisible()" data-bind="visible: isCustomVisible()">
                <div class="selectmenu-item">
                    <button class="selectmenu-item-action" type="button"
                       translate="'Custom'"
                       ko-visible="!isCustomVisible()"
                       data-bind="
                            click: function () {
                                $data.showCustom()
                                    .discardEditing();
                            }"/>
                </div>
                <div class="selectmenu-item-edit" keyboard="13: applyCustom">
                    <input class="admin__control-text" type="text" ko-value="customValue" hasFocus="isCustomVisible()"/>
                    <button class="action-save" type="button" click="applyCustom">
                        <span translate="'Save'"/>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<label class="admin__control-support-text" translate="'per page'" attr="for: index"/>
```

Here i have added data-bind in second li.

After making the changes, execute folllogin commands.

```
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/*
rm -rf pub/static/adminhtml/*
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

truncate ui_bookmarks table in mysql
```

It should work.

Comment: Thank you Yash, It's working fine

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module [Namespace]/[Module]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js add this

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Ui/Magento_Ui/js/view/messages.js':'[Namespace]_[Module]/js/view/messages.js'
    }
}};
```

**your overridden js file should be here**

```
[Namespace]_[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade` && `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

read more here: [Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

Comment: Tried your solution 
But unable to remove "Custom" and "200" options from admin grid