# How to change products per page from category admin

Tags: magento2

I want to assign massive products to any category using the category default page. But I am unbaled to show the maximum product on the grid the maximum limit is 200 products, how can I change these values and set custom values as we do in the products grid. So that I check as many products to select and assign to the category I am using Magento 2.3.3

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quick and temporary solution is, do inspect of your dropdown source in browser, and update dropdown value from `200` to `1000` or any value you want, and search

The actual solution is to override the file, you can follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/269318/31910)

> vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\js\grid\paging\sizes.js

Afther this update the option array

```
    options: {
        '20': {
            value: 20,
            label: 20
        },
        '30': {
            value: 30,
            label: 30
        },
        '50': {
            value: 50,
            label: 50
        },
        '100': {
            value: 100,
            label: 100
        },
        '200': {
            value: 200,
            label: 200
        },
        '1000': {
            value: 1000,
            label: 1000
        }
    },
```

After deployment script every admin grid will have above dropdown options

Comment: I am wondering if all admin grids are using sizes.js file for values, then why there is a difference in dropdown values, as in product grid there is an option for custom also, but when I try to view products from category page and want to assign products to category I am unable to see such options of the dropdown.