# How to override both shipping.html and shipping.js file in custom module magento 2

Tags: shipping, magento2.3, knockoutjs, requirejs

**override both shipping.html and shipping.js**

I am trying to override shipping.js file in magento 2 but can not working.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
paths: {
    'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'VendorName_Namespace/template/shipping',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/shipping': 'VendorName_Namespace/js/shipping'
    }
};
```

Comment: Location of  requirejs-config.js file ?

Comment: You can check this link, it can help https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2

Comment: where you can override shipping.js ? in  module or theme?

Comment: @SavanPatel I want to override shipping.js file in my custom module. location is VendorName/Namespace/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Comment: @Pratikojha Try to do Below Answer

Comment: @SavanPatel bro that code only override html file what about js file

Comment: @Pratikojha try updated answer

Comment: @SavanPatel Thanks for your efforts, I already solved my issue, Thanks for your time and efforts you have given, you are awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution of my question.

How to override both shipping.html and shipping.js.

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    paths: {
         'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': 'VendorName_Namespace/template/shipping',
         'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': 'VendorName_Namespace/js/view/shipping'
      }
};
```

Answer (score 6):

Try to use mixin:

> app/code/SR/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                'SR_Checkout/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

> app/code/SR/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/mixin/shipping-mixin.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko'
    ], function (
        $,
        ko
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return function (target) {
            return target.extend({
                /**
                 * Show address form popup
                 */
                showFormPopUp: function () {

                    this._super();
                }
            });
        }
    }
);
```

***Clear browser js cache, remove pub/static if your magento mode is not developer. Clear cache.***

Answer (score 0):

You can override using map and the shipping js is inside `js/view` directory:

```
    var config = {
        map: {
            '*': {
                "Magento_Checkout/template/shipping.html": "VendorName_Namespace/template/shipping.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping": "VendorName_Namespace/js/shipping"
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: i want to override both html and js will it work?

Comment: Yes, The same way you can override html.

Comment: I have updated code for you.

Comment: not working bro

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
    var config = {
paths: {
    'Magento_Checkout/template/shipping': '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/template/shipping',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
                        '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]/js/view/shipping'
    }
};
```

> 2.app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
>
> 3.app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html

After run the upgrade and static-conent:deploy

Comment: in this how to override shipping.js file