# How do I add a new JS function via mixin to the Magento checkout payment page's shipping information section?

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento2.4, mixins

I am trying to add a mixin in Magento 2 for the checkout/payment page shipping info section.

There is an existing section in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.html` as follows:

```
<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
   <text args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
   <br/>
</each>
```

I want to create a myNewFunction() and call it from here. So, I have temporarily added `if="$parent.myNewFunction(element)"` to it, like this:

```
<each args="data: address().customAttributes, as: 'element'">
   <text if="$parent.myNewFunction(element)" args="$parent.getCustomAttributeLabel(element)"/>
   <br/>
</each>
```

That pre-existing function `getCustomAttributeLabel` is defined in `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default.js`.

This is where I need to add my `myNewFunction()` at. I don't want to override that entire file and duplicate it into my theme, so I am trying to add the function to it via mixin.

To do this, I have stubbed out a module: `app/code/MyCompany`.

In this module, I have created:

`app/code/MyCompany/Checkout/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`

with this code:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default': {
                'MyCompany_Checkout/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Then I created the mixin itself in:

`app/code/MyCompany/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping-information/address-renderer/default-mixin.js`

with this code:

```
define([
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function (Component, _, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            myNewFunction: function (element) {
                console.log(element);
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I currently have deploy mode set to "development" in Magento. Nonetheless, I have tried removing all the var/* files, generating static content again, and clearing the cache, for good measure.

No matter what, upon loading the checkout/payment page, I keep getting this JS error in the console:

`$parent.myNewFunction is not a function`

What am I doing wrong here?

I suspected the module needs to have a register.php? Or the module is not loading? Yet, I have seen plenty of other examples such as [this guide](https://www.magedelight.com/resources/a-detailed-guide-on-using-mixins-in-magento-2/), this Magento [mixin stackoverflow question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/275627/how-to-override-both-shipping-html-and-shipping-js-file-in-custom-module-magento), and [this example on how to add shipping.js functionality via mixin](https://newbedev.com/magento2-override-magento-checkout-view-frontend-web-js-view-shipping-js), none of which mention doing anything more with the module other than declaring the `requirejs-config.js` and the mixin JS file itself.

Comment: yes registration.php and module.xml file is required to register the module. so do needfull.