# When change a swatch option how to get a selected simple product in category product listing page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category-products

When change a  swatch option how to get a selected simple product id from configurable in category product listing page in Magento 2

when I select a swatch option, I was get a option id, from the option id how to get a  simple product id from configurable product

Refer image : https://prnt.sc/ntsay1

code:

> app\code\Cm\Preorder\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
requirejs(['jquery','underscore'], function(jQuery,_){
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
        jQuery( '[class*="swatch-opt"]' ).on('click', '.swatch-option', function() {

            selpro();

        });
    });
    function selpro () {
        var selected_options = {};
        jQuery('div.swatch-attribute').each(function(k,v){
            var attribute_id    = jQuery(v).attr('attribute-id');
            var option_selected = jQuery(v).attr('option-selected');
            // console.log(attribute_id, option_selected);
            if(!attribute_id || !option_selected){ return;}
            selected_options[attribute_id] = option_selected;
        });
             console.log(selected_options);

    }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Create plugin to add quantity to the JS config to get from swatch renderer

Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable">
        <plugin name="vendor_configurable_product_configurable"
                type="vendor\module\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type\Configurable"
                sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Create a plugin file with quantity script below in 
vendor\module\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type\Configurable.php

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Plugin\Block\ConfigurableProduct\Product\View\Type;

use Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Json\DecoderInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;

class Configurable
{

    protected $jsonEncoder;
    protected $jsonDecoder;
    protected $stockRegistry;

    public function __construct(
        EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        DecoderInterface $jsonDecoder,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
    ) {

        $this->jsonDecoder = $jsonDecoder;
        $this->jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
    }

    // Adding Quantitites (product=>qty)
    public function aroundGetJsonConfig(
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {
        $quantities = [];
        $config = $proceed();
        $config = $this->jsonDecoder->decode($config);

        foreach ($subject->getAllowProducts() as $product) {
            $stockitem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem(
                $product->getId(),
                $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
            $quantities[$product->getId()] = $stockitem->getQty();
        }

        $config['quantities'] = $quantities;

        return $this->jsonEncoder->encode($config);
    }
}
```

And your phtml looks like

```
<span class="classname"><?php echo $_product->getId(); ?></span>
```

You can get product quantity from swatches you need to override `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` function `_Rebuild` add following code..

```
 //Check weather product list page or view page
    if ($('body.catalog-product-view').size() <= 0) {
        if( controls.size() == selected.size()){
            var productQty = $widget.options.jsonConfig.quantities[this.getProduct()];
            $widget.element.parents('.product-item-info').find('.classname').html(productQty);
        }
    }
```

finally it looks like

```
       _Rebuild: function () {
            var $widget = this,
                controls = $widget.element.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass + '[attribute-id]'),
                selected = controls.filter('[option-selected]');

            // Enable all options
            $widget._Rewind(controls);

            // done if nothing selected
            if (selected.size() <= 0) {
                return;
            }

    //Check weather product list page or view page
    if ($('body.catalog-product-view').size() <= 0) {
        if( controls.size() == selected.size()){
            var productQty = $widget.options.jsonConfig.quantities[this.getProduct()];
            $widget.element.parents('.product-item-info').find('.classname').html(productQty);
        }
    }

            // Disable not available options
            controls.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this),
                    id = $this.attr('attribute-id'),
                    products = $widget._CalcProducts(id);

                if (selected.size() === 1 && selected.first().attr('attribute-id') === id) {
                    return;
                }

                $this.find('[option-id]').each(function () {
                    var $element = $(this),
                        option = $element.attr('option-id');

                    if (!$widget.optionsMap.hasOwnProperty(id) || !$widget.optionsMap[id].hasOwnProperty(option) ||
                        $element.hasClass('selected') ||
                        $element.is(':selected')) {
                        return;
                    }

                    if (_.intersection(products, $widget.optionsMap[id][option].products).length <= 0) {
                        $element.attr('disabled', true).addClass('disabled');
                    }
                });
            });
        },
```

You can add your logic here instead of adding scripts in phtml files.

To override js file copy from `vendor/magento/module-swatches/view/frontend/web/js/swatch-renderer.js` to `app/design/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Swatches/web/js/swatch-renderer.js`
Run upgrade and content deploy to see changes

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: You can get product id here and pass to custom controller for php code

Comment: You can override js file by module...check this out - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2#60667

Comment: Override is not working?

Comment: Did you run upgrade and deploy commands?

Comment: s i  did it  php bin/magento setup:upgrade and php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: can you pls check `pub/static/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/en_US/Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js` your changes affected?

Comment: see this https://prnt.sc/ntuxyj

Comment: Yes...Does this file has your `console.log();` code?

Comment: see this https://prnt.sc/ntv1am

Comment: OMG....my mistake...:-)..check updated ans

Comment: its working how to get a id in  list.phtml  https://prnt.sc/ntv7ig

Comment: list.phtml means....Can you pls explain exact requirement? why do u need id here?

Comment: i want to get a simple product id  from configurable option in category product listing page

Comment: You got it already using above code...did u have logic to use php using this product id? then we need to work more for this

Comment: i get it into js file fine ok but i want to print a product id in  each list

Comment: how to print in the phtml file

Comment: then you can use `jQuery('.classname').html(this.getProduct());`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ntvfy5

Comment: Please see this https://prnt.sc/ntvhj7

Comment: how did you printed 1225? what is the class of the div?

Comment: Pls wait...working on it

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94151/discussion-on-answer-by-ranganathan-when-change-a-swatch-option-how-to-get-a-sel).

Comment: $productid = $_product->getId(); 
print_r($productid); i m using this code in list.phtml
to get a product id

Comment: You need to create html tag in list.phtml and add updated js code....tested ..it will work

Comment: i m getting 2 id  https://prnt.sc/ntwcy3

Comment: after click a option i need a simple product id alone

Comment: Have you get the simple product id?

Comment: remove your code in phtml file `$productid = $_product->getId(); print_r($productid);`

Comment: i removed it already

Comment: Check your side....we didn't display the configurable product id in above code....and once u clicked the swatches it will replace the simple product id

Comment: got result?.....else post your list.phtml screenshot ..

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ntxb4j

Comment: i got a simple product id

Comment: but i load with simple product id  i didnt get a stock item

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ntxcqo

Comment: No no......we need to execute your stockqty script through ajax....thats y i asked your php logic pa...my code only refresh the `classname` tag

Comment: its working only in the side of script runs, its not get into the php code

Comment: Yes ....if you want to display the product quantity ...need to work around and let you know shortly

Comment: pls check updated ans

Comment: its just display the qty and product id  through script but i have to use  a qty and product through php logic

Comment: You can use your php logic in above plugin class...and display using js only possible.....else u need to use ajax

Comment: in swatch_renderer.js  how i get a main product id

Comment: create a hidden field under `classname` tag with value of `$_product->getId();` and you can get by `$widget.element.parents('.product-item-info').find('HIDDENFIELD_ID').val();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94213/discussion-between-divya-sekar-and-ranganathan).

Comment: @Ranganathan does it work if its custom swatch.

Comment: @insoftservice - custom swatch means?

Comment: @Ranganathan we have created color swatches attributes with "Catalog Input Type for Store Owner " as Visual Swatch

Comment: Please ask a separate question with full details...May be someone knows solution for your requirement

Comment: VERY HELPFULL! THANKS!

Comment: @Ranganathan can you please send this as I have implemented it but not works for me.

Comment: What is the error you got in your env @PratikKamani

Comment: @Ranganathan could you please give me solution for this  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347296/can-we-get-quantity-of-simple-product-in-configurable-swatches

Answer (score 8):

You can find `prodcutId` from `[Magento_Root]\vendor\magento\module-swatches\view\frontend\web\js\swatch-renderer.js`

find `_OnClick` function.

```
_OnClick: function ($this, $widget) {
        var $parent = $this.parents('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeClass),
            $label = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeSelectedOptionLabelClass),
            attributeId = $parent.attr('attribute-id'),
            $input = $parent.find('.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput);

        if ($widget.inProductList) {
            $input = $widget.productForm.find(
                '.' + $widget.options.classes.attributeInput + '[name="super_attribute[' + attributeId + ']"]'
            );
        }

        if ($this.hasClass('disabled')) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this.hasClass('selected')) {
            $parent.removeAttr('option-selected').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $input.val('');
            $label.text('');
        } else {
            $parent.attr('option-selected', $this.attr('option-id')).find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
            $label.text($this.attr('option-label'));
            $input.val($this.attr('option-id'));
            $this.addClass('selected');
            console.log($this.attr('option-id')); // Here you can find selected simple product id
        }

        $widget._Rebuild();

        if ($widget.element.parents($widget.options.selectorProduct)
                .find(this.options.selectorProductPrice).is(':data(mage-priceBox)')
        ) {
            $widget._UpdatePrice();
        }

        $widget._LoadProductMedia();
        $input.trigger('change');
    },
```

It will help you.

Comment: how to get in list.phtml file

Comment: you can add new hidden field and update on click event. after that you will get that hidden field value in list.phtml.
Make sure unique value to get that.