# How to upgrade a jQuery library version?

Tags: magento2, jquery

The version of jQuery in lib is 1.14.0. I want to upgrade to 3.0.0.Tried making changes in theme `require.js` and keeping the new version file in web/js folder of theme, but, it's affecting other js which searches those files in wrong location.

For example in require i gave the path as js/jquery as it is web/js folder. But, the `validate.js` file loaction is changed to `js/jquery/validate.js`

Answer (score 0):

Original file path is here

**magento\vendor\magento\magento2-base\lib\web\jquery.js**

You should overwrite in your theme so path will be

**magento\app\design\frontend\Custom\YourTheme\web\js\jquery.js**

How to override JS file

[Extending / Overriding JS in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2)

Comment: hi, @Rathod, how to update knockout js and jquery-ui version as well?