# How do I know where to put a js file to override a core js file

Tags: magento2

I want to override the js file located in `vendor/magento/module-rule/view/adminhtml/rules.js`

I know I have to go in my `app/design/adminhtml` folder, but after that I'm lost.

Also is there something more to do than just adding the file there ?

Thanks.

EDIT: Tried this but it's not working : `app/design/adminhtml/default/Magento_Rule/web/js/rules.js`

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2 and also https://www.scommerce-mage.com/blog/override-core-javascript-files-magento-2.html

Comment: Already seen both but it but doesn't help me that much to find the good path for my js to be.

Comment: Kurano, please paste your code someone definitely answer.

Comment: Well what code do you want me to paste @HiteshBalpande ?  The rules.js one ?  It doesn't really matter (it's the core one). What I am looking for isn't the code itself (a simple console.log is good enough at this point). What I am looking for is where and how to ovverride the rules.js files located in `vendor/magento/module-rule/view/adminhtml/rules.js`

Comment: When I look into the docs and answers they are always either speaking about frontend or backend but not for a vendor/Magento/Module-XXX

Comment: You need to create an admin theme and apply it to see changes.

Answer (score 0):

Please copy below 2 files in your custom module.

> Namespace\YourModule\view\adminhtml\requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Rule/rules':'Namespace_YourModule/your_rules'
        }
    }
};

//Above  'Magento_Rule/rules' represents vendor\magento\module-rule\view\adminhtml\web\rules.js path

//and    'Namespace_Module/your_rules' represents Namespace\YourModule\view\adminhtml\web\your_rules.js
```

> Now copy vendor\magento\module-rule\view\adminhtml\web\rules.js to
>   your custom module
>   Namespace\YourModule\view\adminhtml\web\your_rules.js location

I hope it will work for you.