# Magento2 JS override

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

How to override **Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/prcr** file in the local module not in theme

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'prcr': 'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/prcr',
            'prcrCountdown': 'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/jquery.countdown'
        },
    },

    shim: {
        'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/jquery.countdown': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/jquery.plugin']
        },
        'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/jquery.plugin': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

I tried below code but not it's not working.

Module path:app/code/Vendor/PlumRocket/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        "*": {
            'prcr': 'Vendor_PlumRocket/js/prcr'
        }
    }
};
```

Or

```
var config = {
        map: {
            "*": {
                'Plumrocket_CartReservation/js/prcr': 'Vendor_PlumRocket/js/prcr'
            }
        }
    };
```

but both method not working.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/60667/85907