# RequireJS module - abstract dependency injection in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, requirejs, dependency-injection

I am searching for a way to extend a JS file which is used as dependency in other JS files for the whole project. The file in use is `Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` and I need to replace it with new file `Custom_Ui/js/form/element/abstract` and then enforce that every `other` file to use my new file instead of the original one. Only other files, because my new file will `extend` the original abstract file. Is that possible? So in practice I need to replace abstract algorithms for the Magento form UI element and make it in the most portable and stable way.

Comment: does the EDIT from this answer work? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/60276/extending-overriding-js-in-magento-2